# Функция в джанго не работает так как мне нужно

Tags: python, django, redis, task, celery

**views**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .apps import price_info

from poeproject.celery import app
from .service import sk
# Create your views here.





items = []
@app.task
def poe():
    global items
    items = sk()
    return items


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse(f'<h1>{price_info}//////////{items}</h1>')
```

Items передается пустой хотя функция отрабатывает каждые 5 минут и я вижу результат в консоли (я был вынужден добавить таск во вьюху)

Comment: Значит код по заполнению массива не вызывается.

Comment: код точно выполняется и я могу отследить его работу в консоли

Comment: Зачем у Вас `global items` в poe()? Я подозреваю что должно вызваться `poe()`, который должен вернуть `items`, так?

Comment: Чтобы функция записывала данные в переменную items которая будет показываться  при запросе страницы

Comment: А нельзя написать `return HttpResponse(f'<h1>{price_info}//////////{sk()}</h1>')`? что будет в таком варианте, может вам `sk()` ничего не возвращает

Comment: к сожалению нет тк функция работает +- минуту. Я не проверял но по идее тогда стр будет очень долго открываться

Comment: кажется функция и вправду не работает хотя принт и консоль показывают что функция проработала 
Я ради эксперимента решил добавить в функцию `items.append(item)` при этом сделал `item = sk()`
но даже так ничего не изменилось